# jquery animate onStart callback

Tags: jquery

Does jquery animate method have a onStart callback. I know about the complete callback but don't see anywhere to use other callbacks like onStart or initialize .

I want onStart callback because when I am calling animate(), it may not start immediately but queued due to previous animation not finished.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Once you call the animate method, it will run while your other javascript code is running.  So the equivalent of having an onStart callback would be putting the code you want to run immediately after the animate method.  Additionally, there is a 'step' function you can use.. http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step   .. I haven't used it, but it seems like you can check for the initial CSS values you're working with and only execute code based on that.  Could be a performance issue though if you're animating a lot of parts.

Comment: This answer is correct for a single animation. However, OP clearly states "_calling animate() [...] may not start immediately but queued due to previous animation not finished_"

Answer (score 2):

`.animation()` have a undocumented `start` options

```
$('.box').animate({left:100},{
    duration:500,
    start:function(){
        console.log('start');
    },
    complete:function(){
        console.log('end');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! this is solution

Answer (score 1):

I've used this method in the past and it seems to work pretty well. Hopefully it can work for you.

Edit (2016/12/06 - Better example of what OP requested)

HTML:

```
<div class="tile">X</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

.tile {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function doMe() {
  console.log('We called a callback function!');
}

$('#tiles .tile').animate({
  'left': '+=500px'
}, {
  duration: 6000,
  step: function(now, fx) {
    var data = $(this).data('anistart');
    if (!data) {
      console.log('We started!');
      $(this).data('anistart', {
        start: fx.start,
        end: fx.end
      });
      doMe();
    }
    console.log('We\'re stepping...');
  },
  complete: function() {
    var data = $(this).data('anistart');
    if (data.end !== parseFloat($(this).css('left'))) {
      $(this).css('left', data.end);
    }
    $(this).removeData('anistart');
    console.log('We ended!');
  }
});
```

On the step function, I'm testing to see if the object has previously set data. If not I set it and then we can call/handle any stuff (i.e. your callback)

On the complete function, I make sure the position is what it should be, if not, I set it. You could most likely do away with the test and just set it, but not sure which one is more of a performance hit (the check or the css set).

So no matter what the case, you set a variable on start, and if its not set then you know its the first time... i.e. its being initialized.

DEMO: [Example of jQuery animate onStart callback](http://codepen.io/cjboco/pen/BQxdyw)

Answer (score 0):

On start occurs when you fire your animation

```
function onStart(){
   $('.box').animate({left:100},500,onComplete())
}
function onStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Way**

I am not very experienced but this is the way to go.

Just insert css method before animate.

Like this:

```
$(this).css({ "display": "block", "opacity": "0" })
        .animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 200);
```